# HashMap cannot be cast to java.sql.Clob

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, hashmap

is there any way to cast HashMap to persist as CLOB in database
let say we have
HashMap<String, String> capitalCities = new HashMap<String, String>();

```
// Add keys and values (Country, City)
capitalCities.put("England", "London");
capitalCities.put("Germany", "Berlin");
capitalCities.put("Norway", "Oslo");
capitalCities.put("USA", "Washington DC");
```

i want to pass this Hasmap as a CLOB in Database via Stored Procedure

eg
callableStatement.setClob(1,(Clob)capitalCities ) - its not working

is there any workaround ?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above code doesn't look like SQL at all.

Comment: Hi i am using callableStatement.setClob(1,(Clob)capitalCities ) statement to persist in db via stored procedure